# Python - how to show differences between two numbers(strings)

Tags: python

```
import random

def run_all():

    print "Welcome"
    name = get_name()
    welcome(name)
    guess = get_guess()
    print guess
    dice1 = get_dice()
    dice2 = get_dice()
    dice3 = get_dice()
    total = dice1 + dice2 + dice3
    print "Dice 1: " + str(dice1)
    print "Dice 2: " + str(dice2)
    print "Dice 3: " + str(dice3)
    print "The dices total sum is:  " + str(total)
    print "Your guess was: " + guess




def get_name():

    '''ask name'''
    return raw_input("Hi, what's your name?")

def welcome(name):

    ''' welcome'''
    print name + ", welcome!"

def get_guess():

    return raw_input("We will throw 3 dices, what do you think the total sum will be? ")

def get_dice():

    return random.randint(1,6)


run_all()
```

**I want to show the player the difference between guess and total, but can't figure out how to.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
difference = abs(total - int(guess))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Hannah you are welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as correct answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
difference = total - int(guess)
```

Comment: Yeah I did notice, I just included it because casting is often good for validation, but I suppose I already showed how to do so with the "guess" variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!